# How to change the text color when textbox content editable false?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, contenteditable

How to change the style when content editable true/false?
Need red color when editable is true, and gray color for when it is false.
Is this possible in CSS?

**Here is my html code:**

```
<body spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" contenteditable="false" style="color:gray;>
  Need to change color of the text when it is false
</body>
```

Comment: You have a missing `"` here `style="color:gray;"`. Also you want to take the style off the `inline`. Because like this the `stylesheet` `color` does — not — work.

Answer (score 3):

Use css slector by `attribute`
Here is the tutorial about selector in css
:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
body[contenteditable="true"]{
    color:red;
}
body[contenteditable="false"]{
    color:grey;
}
```

Comment: @Gokul Kumar i think this is the answer you were looking for